# What role did Jews play in the Punic Wars?

Tags: roman-republic, jews, carthage, punic-wars

There were Jewish communities throughout the Mediterranean at the time of the [Punic Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punic_wars)? What role if any, did Jews play in these wars?

Comment: Any particular reason to expect such a role?

Comment: I find your first sentence, stated as fact, somewhat unlikely. Do you have a reference for it? However, the Jews and the Phonecians were quite closely related, and Carthage was essentially a Phonecian colony gone independent.

Comment: I would add to T.E.D.'s statement, that the Phonecians were related (being Semitic): Carthage achieved independence (and the hegemony over the Phonecian colonies in the western Mediterranean) nearly four hundred years before the start of the first Punic war.

Comment: @NathanCooper - Not only were they both semetic, they were both Central Semetic. Not only were they both Central Semetic, but within that group they were both Northwest Semetic (as was Aramaic, which much of the Torah was written in). Not only were they both Northwest Semetic, but within that grouping they were both Cananite ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canaanite_languages ). There's a nice tree here: http://mathildasanthropologyblog.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/semitic-tree.jpg . It would not be unreasonable to look upon the ancient Jews as the Phonecians' "country cousins".

Comment: @T.E.D., so wouldnt that make them more physicaly identical to the canaanites (whom were hamites, Negroid)? Would the ancient Israelites be darker skinned with kinky hair like the other Canaanites and Hamites? I mean Hebrew is one of the early Asiatic-African languages.

Comment: @eliyah - OK, well you have the first part right at least. Hebrews and Canaanites would probably have looked almost identical. But don't mix up biblical "Hamites" (essentially neighboring tribes who weren't quite Jewish), with "Hamitic Languages" (an obsolete classification of all the Semitic languages of Africa, thrown together for no good reason), or with "Hamitic People" (a term formerly used for sub-saharan African semites, who are darker-skinned because of where they live, but who are otherwise completely unrelated to the Niger-Congo and Nilo-Saharan people who used to be called "Negro")

Comment: ...while we don't have photos of course, its a pretty good bet both peoples looked very much like modern Arabs, as Arabic is I believe the closest-related modern language to both (its also Central Semitic).

Comment: @T.E.D., The Philistines and the Canaanites were presumed Africanoid due to there descendence from Cush (father of the Ethiopians). The Philistines and Canaanites were basically Ethiopian colonies, hence many thought the Hebrews to be of Ethiopian origen according to ancient sources.

Comment: @eliyah - Do you have a source for all that? AFAIK, that is *not* the current canonical understanding of the origin of either of those peoples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe we can spit this up into three parts:

**Roman Jewish Community:**
*"Jews have lived in Rome for over 2,000 years [...] They may even have established a community there as early as the second pre-Christian century, for in the year 139 B.C. the pretor Hispanus issued a decree expelling all Jews who were not Italian citizens" [Jewish Encyclopaedia](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12816-rome#1005)*
So we can pretty much discount there role there.

**Jews in the Levant**
At the time part of the [Seleucid Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_Empire). The [Battle of Magnesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Magnesia) between them and Rome as well as the [Treaty of Apamea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Apamea) are in scope. [Jewish nationalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maccabees) against the Seleucids is also in scope. It seems Jews here were largely antagonistic to the Seleucids who were at war with Rome, who were at war with Carthage. But no direct link to Roman wars in the western Mediterranean here, I think.

**Carthaginian Jewish Community**
[Algerian Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algerian_Jews): "There is evidence of a Jewish presence in Algeria since at least the late Roman period". Out of scope, probably.
[Tunisian Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisian_Jews) : "The ruins of an ancient synagogue dating back to the 3rd-5th century CE was discovered by the French captain Ernest De Prudhomme". Excellent. There were also jews in Carthage according to the [Jewish Encyclopaedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4085-carthage#anchor3), based on evidence from the Talmud. So Jews would have been around in numbers during the Punic Wars.

Did they do much fighting? There is evidence for Jewish mercenaries in Egypt [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/882-africa) and in the Seleucid shpere of influence (Crete etc) [here, search for jewish](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_B09AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). There are stories of a Jew (I think) called Zepho running away to Carthage and becoming a general (in that first "here" link) but I think it's too early in history and I don't stand by it's validity.

I would say there was a community there were involved in so far as they lived, worked, traded there. But I don't think there's much to write as far as "Jewish involvement goes".

Comment: Same deal with [Jews in Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Spain#Early_history_.28before_300.29), who were there at the time, possibly. They probably weren't in [Gaul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_France#Roman-Gallic_epoch).

Comment: What about the community of [Djerba](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3905/2177)?

Comment: Good answer, but I think that Zepho is a bit mischaracterized. Following Nathan's link I read that "The Hebrew Josephus (Josippon, i. chap. ii.), indeed, reports that Zepho, son of Eliphaz, son of Esau, who was brought to Egypt as a captive by the viceroy Joseph, escaped thence to Carthage, where he was appointed general by King Angias". Two points to note here: (1) A grandson of Esau is not really a Jew. A not-too-distant cousin of Jews, rather. (2) Josippon is **not** Josephus, it's a medieval compilation of various legends, plus some material from Josephus thrown in.

Comment: So Zepho is probably just a tall medieval tale. A pity.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Yes seems untrue. But I think the [chain](http://bible.cc/genesis/36.htm) goes: Zepho, son of [Eliphaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliphaz), son of [Esau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esau), son of [Isaac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac). Seems very Jewish, but we know that paternal links aren't enough and I think they had become [Edomites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edomites) and hostile to the Israelites. However, I think that's enough quoting sketchy mythology for one day.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Djerba did have a [Jewish community](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H4QeOGV_zl4C&pg=PA270&lpg=PA270&dq=Djerba+punic+wars&source=bl&ots=e6ip_U4goU&sig=XHIj0EetvIGg_WRGXTx0QsdGhKA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h8nqULSuAobM0AWk0oG4Aw&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Djerba%20punic%20wars&f=false) at some point and was an important to commerce at the time. A Roman fleet did [run aground](http://www.allempires.com/article/index.php?q=war_first_punic) there, but re-floated.

Comment: @NathanCooper: Esau and his progeny are not canonically considered Jews. He sort of opted out of the tribe.

Comment: Is it possible to estimate the percentage of Jews in those communities?